# Regex keyword suggestion

Tags: php, regex

I have the following dataset:

```
names = ["brad pitt", "george clooney", "james cameron"];
```

I need a regex that matches "brad pitt" and "george clooney" given:

```
"brad peter clooney"
```

Also, it should match: `"brad pitt"` when query is, `"brad peter pitt"`

Please note that I am using PHP and I can split the query and manipulate it. for example I can try this:

```
((brad)+.*(peter)+.*(pitt)+.*+)
```

but its not going to match since I have 1 or more after each name, and if it put * (0 or more) its going to match all records since it also means match nothing.

Comment: By what means does `brad peter clooney` match `brad pitt` and `george clooney`? I find this a bit unclear. Is the underlying question "how to check if a given string contains one of a set of strings"?

Comment: This is a keyword suggestion service where if you type in: brad peter clooney, the system should be able to suggest both names. I could use any of the three word like "/(.*brad.*)|(.*peter.*)|(.*clooney.*)i/" but this is gonna match so many other items. So for example if you search for brad pitt. its also gonna bring "brad james"

Comment: For such a search, I'd recommend using an iterative approach over the words in each string rather than regex, for the sake of clarity.  I'd assume this approach would also execute quicker than running a regex with numerous OR delimiters, but this would need testing.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to match a string if it has any of the words in it. 
For that you could split the string on `\s+` and use each word in an expression like:

```
word1|word2|word3
```

You may also want to add some `\b`s and `/i`, for example (`//` quoted this time):

```
/\b(?:word1|word2|word3)\b/i
```

Or you could use three separate expressions or `indexOf()` checks.

Comment: isnt this the same as: "/(.*brad.*)|(.*peter.*)|(.*clooney.*)i/" In this case, it breaks down the keywords, so also "brad james" comes up when you search for "brad pitt"

Answer (score 0):

ok here is a simple idea:

```
$arr = array("brad pitt", "george clooney", "james cameron");
$str = "brad peter clooney";

foreach($arr as $val)
{
   $tmpptrn = str_replace(" ", "|", $val);
   $pattern = "/($tmpptrn)/i";

   if(preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches))
   {
       //do whatever with the results

       $match = $matches[1][0];
       if(!empty($match))
       {
           $arra[] = array_filter($arr, function($el) use ($match) { return ( strpos($el, $match) !== false ); });

       }

   }
}

//print out the results
print_r($arra);
```